# "Update driver software" not showing. :(

Tags: windows

I've followed tutorials installing arduino drivers for a while, but this is getting in my way:

[image: The "Update driver software" button doesn't show!]

The all-important "Update driver software" button isn't showing? Can anyone explain this and how I can fix it? Many thanks!

Comment: Simple solution: Upgrade to Windows 10 and you won't need the drivers. Ditch Windows 8, it's the most dire piece of *&$"!^ ever created. Even worse than Windows ME.

Comment: What arduino are you using official/unofficial? Using any tools to connect the arduino to the pc? I would recommend to reinstall arduino. And or try connecting the device to another USB port

Comment: I'm using arduino UNO R3 , I'm using USB to connect my arduino. I'll try another port

Comment: Thanks, but I'd get tonnes of new problems if I upgrade to windows 10. Lots of software I have has admitted to glitching a lot on windows 10.

Comment: But I am considering upgrading to windows 10.

Comment: do you know any other solutions?

Comment: Upgrade to Linux and you won't need any drivers either.